# Graphics design for tilt sensor using pitch and roll value

Tags: c, math, pitch, tilt-sensor

I am trying to design graphics based on the pitch and roll value using 'C'. for that i have a tilt sensor (accelerometer) which spits out the roll and pitch value. I want to make use of a graphics which should be able to show me the direction in which i tilt the tilt sensor.

Below is some code from my program which determines the angle ( based on pitch and roll value).

szBuff[] having data in R:SXXX.XX P:SXXX.XX\r\n  format

where S= sign and R= roll, P= pitch.

```
    if (szBuff[2] == '+' && szBuff[12] == '-')
    {
       -------------------------------------    
       if(pitch>roll){                             
        Angle = atan(pitch / pitch- roll);             // Insert formula here 
       -------------------------------------
      }
    }
```

Here pitch and roll are without sign.

I draw a line which deflects based on the pitch and roll value. Using above algorithm i calculate the Angle with which it has to deflect.

```
 line((left+150),(top+150),((left+150)+150*cos(Angle)),((top+150)+150*sin(Angle)));
```

I need a mathematical equation which could fulfill my objective. Angle = atan(pitch / pitch -roll) doesn't draw the required angle. Only for same pitch and roll it holds true and throws 90 degree( which means i am tilting the sensor in forward direction). So could you please replace the Angle formula with some mathematical expression which could generate the tilting angle based on roll and pitch.

I have attached screen shot of output. If you find my question ambiguous then please excuse and suggest for betterment of question so that i get it answered. [image]

Comment: will the two argument version `atan2(y,x)` help you? Thats the standard way to get an angle from x and y coordinates.

Comment: Verify that your tilt-table is returning values in the units you are using (radians/degrees) and then make sure you calibrate the range of motion of the tilt-table to the the range of angles represented. Write your needed equations out by hand and plug in the numbers the tilt-table is spitting out. The good old slow scientific method...

Comment: pitch and roll are in terms of degree. I don't have info about X, Y, Z i want to make use of serial spited data by tilt sensor to draw the line which moves in the direction you tilt, your tilt sensor in.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, pitch and roll are angles. I assume that roll is the angle which rotates about the vertical axis and pitch is the angle which rotates about the horizontal axis.

Then you can calculate the 3d position as:

```
x = sin(roll) * cos(pitch)
y = sin(pitch)
z = cos(roll) * cos(pitch)
```

Both `roll` and `pitch` should contain their signs.

It seems that you want to project this vector on a fixed plane, probably the xz-plane. Then you would draw this using:

```
line( left+150,
      top+150,
      left+150+150*x,
      top+150+150*z );
```